# select data which will start displaying in 48 hours from now

Tags: php, mysql

Find all the articles which will start displaying in 48 hours from now
I need to get data which will display in next 48 hours only.

**MySql Query**

```
SELECT * from articles WHERE articles.start_date > CURDATE() + INTERVAL 48 HOUR
```

Today is 2015-04-15 and i am Getting result wrong. I have 2015-04-17 in database but not showing. I only need to get 2015-04-17 not all others.

[image]

Comment: `>= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 48 HOUR`

Comment: As you gave `date > 48 hours`... Its displaying all the records which are greater than 48 hours... So i think you have to change ur query to `date >= 48 hours` and `date < [some interval]`

Comment: I think you can give your query like this...

`SELECT * from articles WHERE articles.start_date >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 48 HOUR AND articles.start_date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 72 HOUR`

Comment: Is this right :

SELECT id, start_date from ad_articles WHERE ad_articles.start_date >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 48 HOUR and ad_articles.start_date <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 48 HOUR;

Comment: if you want this then instead of this it should be equal to...........like SELECT id, start_date from ad_articles WHERE ad_articles.start_date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 48 HOUR;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to get 2015-04-17, why don't you try to use equal.

Try This :

```
SELECT * from articles WHERE articles.start_date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 48 HOUR
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use >= INTERVAL 2 day  and <= INTERVAL 2 day
try this

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE articles.start_date >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 day AND articles.start_date <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 day;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT * from articles WHERE articles.start_date >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 48 HOUR and articles.start_date <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 day;
```

Comment: it will give me all the 3rd result of 17th, 19th ,20 th date.
but i need only 17th.

Comment: then u have to add date < condition too

Comment: What is in anyinterval ?

Comment: the time till which you want to restrict result

Comment: or this SELECT id, start_date from ad_articles WHERE ad_articles.start_date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 48 HOUR;

Comment: Just add ORDER BY articles.start_date  LIMIT 1 at the end of the query, if you need only one result.